# How to extend a class and override one of its variables in TypeScript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

What is the best way to extend a class that gets the same variables and methods as the original class except for one variable, which should be also extended?

See example below:

```
class A {
    polygon: "triangle" | "rectangle"
    name: string 
    doSomething: () => void
}
    
class B extends A {
    polygon: "triangle" | "rectangle" | "circle"
    // should keep name, doSomething as it is
}
```

I have tried doing polygon = super.polygon but TypeScript says Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'. I've also tried declaring this on the constructor but it forces me to call super() with all the arguments, so I can't override the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got `extends` backwards, unfortunately. Roughly speaking, when `B extends A` it means that `B` is a [*subtype*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) of `A`.  That means you should be able to assign a value of type `B` to a variable of type `A`.  You can also think of this in terms of [*substitutability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitutability): if `B extends A` it means that you can *substitute* a value of type `B` for a value of type `A` without anyone noticing.  If you ask for a `A` and I give you an `B` and something goes wrong, then `B extends A` is not true.

Given your definition of `A`, the following function should be fine... and the compiler produces no warning:

```
function foo(a: A) {
  const unicodeShapes = {
    triangle: "△",
    rectangle: "▭"
  }
  return (unicodeShapes[a.polygon].repeat(10));
}

const a = new A();
a.polygon = "triangle";
console.log(foo(a)); // "△△△△△△△△△△"
```

But now think about what would happen if your `B` definition were accepted as valid:

```
const b = new B();
b.polygon = "circle";
console.log(foo(b)); // okay for the compiler, but
// RUNTIME ERROR! unicodeShapes[a.polygon] is undefined
```

If `B extends A`, then `foo(b)` should be acceptable... `foo` wants an `A`, and `B extends A` implies that `b`, a value of type `B`, is substitutable for a value of type `A`.  But of course there's a big problem doing this at runtime.

So you cannot "extend" classes this way without leading to type safety issues.

---

What can you do instead?  Given the simple example code, you could just flip which class is the parent and which is the child:

```
class B {
  polygon: "triangle" | "rectangle" | "circle" = "triangle" 
  name: string = ""
  doSomething: () => void = () => { }
}
class A extends B {
  polygon: "triangle" | "rectangle" = "triangle"
}
```

---

But if you really want to use something like `class B extends A`, so that `b instanceof A` should be `true`, without requiring that `B` be a true subtype of `A`, you can do something like this with [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys):

```
const _A: new () => Omit<A, "polygon"> = A;

class B extends _A {
  polygon: "triangle" | "rectangle" | "circle" = "triangle"
}
```

Here we have created `_A` and told the compiler that it constructs instances of `A` without a known `polygon` property, and assigned the `A` constructor to it.  We have *widened* the type of `A`, which is a type-safe operation (at least when you read properties only).

Then we make `B` extend `_A` instead of `A`.  This is more or less the same as your code at runtime, but the compiler is now happy with it because it does not see `B` as trying to be a subtype of `A`.  You cannot use a `B` wherever you'd use an `A`:

```
console.log(foo(b)); // compiler error!
// -----------> ~
// Argument of type 'B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'.
```

Yay!  This might have some observable side effects in TypeScript, because the compiler expects subclasses to form subtypes, so be careful with this sort of thing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=20&pln=31&pc=49#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgewEYBsJiQG8AoJJeHEKKJAQSNLKRgxwE8BzDYALiQCIALmgCWIYBzz8kAHwFoI8QeMkRpAXgHCxEqYzKhIfKNolJN-fvqQATDAGUMkQQAsREvgAoAlOYB8SABuGCI25kg+-kRIAL6McYwUVDQAQkgQAB6CEMA2NPQkTMysnNx8QqIqUrLyisq6ajX88CJoFI0W2lWNAPQ96WiYaACE8cTECcSG0HCISABiOCIwDImU1EhphUws7Fy8WpUN0nL8CkrdJwItbdWdR6pWRdPGphzhltZ2js5uHhG+dQBYKhcKRIHRBJkOJkJIbeiZbK5VIMIq7UoHCo6R5Nc71HH3bF6aHjSZw-Ko4p7MqHImNU54y4fLrHRgvJAmURmCxPWwOJwQVzuDheQHAkJhTTggKEWITcbwbgmJAAfVofGAEAA7gCogB5MAiQQAHloABoBOj9vwAppaABuBXrFGInJ5VUFRhWmlYpkMup+66tdoaWmXeXEABmAFdgEoRNwkJGMBhPCA+LRfNtFcBlbGRIqbBB7C4QDBoOFtmQWapyoBm0n4ZusjIa5UAtaS8mFIBSCaNoYARfOF4ul8tQADaIAAdN7gABdKcKcsgQSeACMAAZvN5HQkc8qQOFNTraD5HdPZ8yHlJHfvWBApzgMBxPMnUyBt-akH0BHW--+AKsYh90EJAsCPbVNjPYgsBnEp9g+G4Q1vJV70fZ9XxTTwsE-b9+ggQYMBGYgfwAWnIijKNIgIAD8SP6Wg0A4aNIGAUCMEjJBBDYcskAAchSPikBEGhgAwUDkhEDhQFwZBBAwZgQDQcBBQIpAOK4njkD42g+KneikAAJQAVQAOQAFQASQAWQAUSQWzDMMvVDOGJAhwwIsSzLaBJzg6l52EqBxmIIA)